# Rocket.Chat Custom JavaScript intercept new message

Tags: javascript, rocket.chat

I would like to know if it possible to intercept new messages as they are recieved with the Rocket.Chat "Custom Scripts" admin section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `/app/ui-message/client/message.js` and inserting the following code into `Template.message.onCreated`

```
...
Template.message.onCreated(function(){
 const {...} ...;

 if(typeof window.onMessage==="function"){
  window.onMessage(msg);
 }

 ...
});
...
```

Then in your Custom JavaScript create a function with the message parameter, like so.

```
window.onMessage=(msg)=>{
 console.log("received message",msg);
}
```

This will allow you to post-process messages without having to recompile Rocket.Chat.